# Agile Development 101 Video

Tags: video, agile

I've been trying to find a good video that I can show at a "Lunch and Learn" on Agile Development / Scrum. Our organization is primarily Waterfall and most people have never even heard of Agile development let alone have any concrete knowledge of the topic. There are plenty of great resources out there that talk about Agile, but they all seem to assume a basic working knowledge of Agile. I can not find one that gives a good, down to earth, introduction to Agile development for those who know nothing about.

Can anyone provide such a link?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: FYI, I created an aggregated answer and marked it community owned.  Since the votes won't buy me anything, feel free to use it as a good reference of the many fine answers submitted below. (and edit and update as necessary.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Autumn of Agile** video-cast series is exactly what you're looking for.

It's produced by Steve, who blogs at [http://unhandled-exceptions.com](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/).

**http://www.autumnofagile.net/**

The quality and depth of the presentation is very good.  You will be impressed.

Comment: I think this has great potential for a quick overview and intorduction to Agile. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Aggregating the answers here as a single answer:

Video Links

- [Introduction to Agile for Traditional Project Managers](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Introduction-Agile-Stacia-Broderick)
- [Autumn of Agile](http://www.autumnofagile.net/)
- [Scrum Et Al: Google Tech Talk](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-7230144396191025011)
- [YouTube Vid about Agile & Business](http://de.youtube.com/watch?v=OWvSnYjqOTQ)
- [Scrum in less than 10 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5k7a9YEoUI) (Hamid Shojaee)

Resource Links

- [Ken Schwaber Videos & Links](http://www.controlchaos.com/)
- [Scrum Alliance](http://www.scrumalliance.org/)
- [Introductory Podcast Re Scrum (audio only)](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ARCast+with+Ron+Jacobs/ARCastnet-The-Agile-Architect-with-Jeffrey-Palermo/)

Answer (score 2):

I liked this when I saw it:

[Introduction to Agile for Traditional Project Managers](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Introduction-Agile-Stacia-Broderick)

From the site:

In this presentation filmed during Agile 2007, Stacia Broderick introduces Agile to traditionally trained project managers by making a comparison between Project Management Institute's (PMI) best practices and their equivalent Agile techniques.

Comment: Good presentation, however, a background in PM really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video called "Scrum et al." which is Ken Schwaber presenting the topic at a Google Tech Talk.

"Google Tech Talks September 5, 2006 Ken Schwaber co-developed the Agile process, Scrum. He is a founder of the Agile Alliance and Scrum .."

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-7230144396191025011

You might also find resources here:

http://www.scrumalliance.org/

Answer (score 1):

There's a series of 2 videos on Agile Development, from the guys of .Net Rocks!. Google for "Venkat Subramaniam on Fundamentals of Agile Design", I think is show no. 73, and see if it fits for your audience. 
There's also an introductory podcast here: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ARCast+with+Ron+Jacobs/ARCastnet-The-Agile-Architect-with-Jeffrey-Palermo/, but is only audio.

Answer (score 1):

Ken Schwaber has a bunch of videos up at http://www.controlchaos.com/. They're somewhat short but I've found watching the videos then discussing the individual topics is a good format for a meeting.

Answer (score 1):

[Hamid Shojaee](http://community.axosoft.com/blogs/hamids/) produced a **[ten minutes video on Scrum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWSXETDWGQ4)** (also available in [High Definition](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5k7a9YEoUI)). It's very rhythmical and amusing. Could be a great start for a discussion for your Lunch'n Learn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any links for you, but I do have one piece of advice that applies when you can't find the resource you need: create it yourself.

If you look long and hard and can't find any video that is right for your group, you can always invest some of your time to create that video.  Then make sure it is prominently available on the internet and someone else in your shoes will have the video they need.